# About Trivial homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

if I want to prove that " there does not exist any homomorphism f : ＜Q,+> → ＜Qpos, x> , x means multiplication
Can I just prove there only exist f is trivial homomorphism?

Thanks

Comment: Since the trivial homomorphism always exists, then how can you possibly prove that there are no homomorphisms??? Do you mean, there are no nontrivial homomorphisms?

Comment: @BrianO  f : ＜Q,+> → ＜Qpos, x> , x means multiplication

Comment: @BrianO yes! I have already solve there only exist trivial homomorphism, so I can directly say there does not exist any homomorphism?

Comment: No, you can't, it makes no sense, given there IS a homomorphism. You can say that there is no nontrivial hom.

Comment: @BrianO thank you，trivial homomorphism always exist? Why?

Comment: Because if $G, H$ are groups then the set $\{(x,e_H)\mid x\in G\}$ always exists, and it IS the trivial hom.